# Cannot connect to MongoDB inside a template

Tags: meteor

I'm still a newbie when it comes to Meteor.

The following code works, I get the list:

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
       {{#each members}}
       {{> MembersList}}
       {{/each}}
    </ul>
</body>

<template name="MembersList">
    <li>{{name}}</li>
</template>
```

To use iron:router in need to put this in another page with {{yield}}, so I need to put it in a template. The other in this template (removed those lines) is visible in the browser, but I don't see the list anymore.

```
<template name="foo">

<ul>
    <li>Test</li>
        {{#each members}}
        {{> MembersList}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="MembersList">
    <li>{{name}}</li>
</template>
```

This is my code to connect with the database, it is the same in both cases. Even if a change body.helper to MembersList.helpers and put another template in it for the `<li>`'s.

```
Members = new Mongo.Collection('members');

    if (Meteor.isClient) {

      Template.body.helpers({
        members: function() {
          return Members.find();
        }
      });
}
```

Is it something to do with `Template.body.helpers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot attach helpers to `body`. Helpers have to be attached to a template.

What you should do is this:

in the HTML:

```
<body>
    {{> membersList}}
</body>

<template name="membersList">
    <ul>
        {{#each members}}
            <li>{{name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

In the JS:

```
Template.membersList.helpers({
    members: function() {
        return Members.find();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks,

I've changed the code, but It still returns no list.

Comment: It might be something obvious to say, but do you have any data in your collection?

Comment: Yes, the `db.members.find()` query in the command line gives several results. It contains the name column.

Comment: Ok, this answer helped. There were some other problems somewhere else I had to cope with, to make this work.

Thanks!

Comment: @Sigurd3K Glad it helped. :) with your data, make sure you are publishing and subscribing the right way. and don't forget to remove the `autopublish` package!